# TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer while creating data generators PyTorch

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, pytorch, data-generation

I am new to PyTorch and I am learning to create batches of data for segmentation. The code is shown below:

```
class NumbersDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.X = list(df['input_img'])
        self.y = list(df['mask_img'])

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.X), len(self.y)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.X[idx], self.y[idx]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataset = NumbersDataset()
    dataloader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=50, shuffle=True, num_workers=2)
    # print(len(dataset))
    # plt.imshow(dataset[100])
    # plt.show()
    print(next(iter(dataloader)))
```

where `df['input_img']` column contains the location of the image (`'/path/to/pic/480p/boxing-fisheye/00010.jpg'`) and `df['mask_img']` contains the location of all the mask images. I am trying to load the images but I get the error:

> TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

However, if I don't use `DataLoader` and just do the following:

```
     dataset = NumbersDataset()
     print(len(dataset))
     print(dataset[10:20])
```

then I get what I expect. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot return a `tuple` for the `__len__` method.  The expected type is `int`

```
# perhaps you can add the list length's for the total length
# but no matter how you choose to implement the method you can
# only return on value of type integer `int`
def __len__(self):
    return len(self.X) + len(self.y)
```

Comment: What if I just return the length of `self.X`? Will it work? I guess it only needs the length so that it can iterate over the values. I know for a fact that length of `X` and `y` is the same

Comment: Then that should be fine. That's more of an implementation detail for you to decide. The error is your attempting to return two values when the `Dataloader` is treating it as a single `int` and failing if it's not.

Comment: Can you tell me why did it work without the `DataLoader`? Is there a difference there?

Comment: Because the `DataLoader` is expecting a single value of type `int` for the length property.  Likely because it's adding or using the value from `__len__` to do some math.  If the value if not an integer then the math fails.  For example running `(1,2)+1` fails because you can't preform math on a type `tuple`

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you